# Some doubts related the resource (drawable) organization into an Android Studio project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable, android-resources

I am very new in Android and I have the following doubts related how to handle images into my project.

I know that I have to put the images into the **/res/drawable/** directory into my project.

To make order I have tryed to split up these images into differend subdirectory.

So for example I have created this subdirectory: **/res/drawable/header/** that contains all the images related to the header of my application.

But when in the XML I do:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:src="@drawable/header/carbonara"/>
```

Android Studio give me an error on this line:

```
android:src="@drawable/header/carbonara"
```

that say to me that: **'/' is not a valid resource name character**

So in Android I really can't create structured and well organized subfolder for my images?

Another doubt is related to the different version fo the **drawable** folder.

I know that I can create a structure like this:

```
res
    drawable-hdpi
    drawable-ldpi
    drawable-mdpi
    .............
    .............
    .............
```

where each **drawable*** contain a specific version of the same images having different pixel density.

Using Android Studio can I automatically generate these folder starting from the **drawable** folder (containing my original images) or have I to create these folder manually and manually change the pixel density using something like Photoshop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Go through this Link -https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html

Here You can upload your images and generate images with different pixel density. Android Studio doesn't support automation for Generating drawable images..!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create different version of drawable then change the view to project from android. then navigate to the **Project name->app->src->main->res** and create different directories for each screen density like hdpi ,mdpi etc. you can take reference from mipmap.

p.s. : For automatic scalling of drawables you can consider the using of svg 
Link: [Developer android link](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html)

Comment: Ok, I know that I can manually create these directory into res and then put inside these directory the different version of the images creating them using Photoshop. My doubt is: Android Studio automatize this function? (creation of the folder and of the image with different pixel density) starting form the original drawable folder?

Comment: Till now i didn't experience this.So may be according to me it is not automatically do that.